# Installing driver for TP-LINK Archer T9UH AC1900 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, software-installation, internet, usb-installation

Recently bought a WiFi booster to combat patchy WiFi in my uni dorm, works perfectly with Windows as driver installation was easy to follow, yet I can't seem to figure out how to install the Ubuntu drivers. The picture attached is the guide to installing with Ubuntu but I can't follow it, could someone really spell it out step by step like I'm 5 years old please

in my /lib/modules directory there are 4 directories, 4.15.0-29-generic, 4.15.0-62-generic, 4.15.0-64-generic, 4.15.0-65-generic, which on of these should I enter? Additionally the guide says to enter the command "make clean" but I receive and error saying I didn't specify a target.

EDIT:

```
uname -r

4.15.0-65-generic

lsusb

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b52d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0106  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

dmesg | grep 88x2bu

[No output]
```

[image]

Comment: You need to open a terminal and run those commands except for step 3, you need to type this: `sudo cp 88x2bu.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless`. Run those commands and post the output if you get any errors.

Comment: @marko in my /lib/modules directory there are 4 directories, 4.15.0-29-generic, 4.15.0-62-generic, 4.15.0-64-generic, 4.15.0-65-generic, which on of these should I enter? Additionally the guide says to enter the command "make clean" but I receive and error saying I didn't specify a target.

Comment: @Retsek 4.15.0-29-generic, 4.15.0-62-generic, 4.15.0-64-generic, and 4.15.0-65-generic are all 'kernels'; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system) . Which  kernel are you now using? Run `uname -r` to find out.

Answer (score 2):

With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au
sudo dkms install rtl8814au/4.3.21
```

Reboot. Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Everything seemed to work perfectly, but the issue is I could connect to the internet before, just it was really slow, since installing the driver on my windows partition there is a drop down menu in which I select "WiFi 2" and then the adapter lights up and I get faster speeds, how do I access the Ubuntu equivalent of this "WiFi 2"?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Windows. Is *WiFi 2* a nearby access point or what? Does it appear when you run: `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: Sorry I was relating it to Windows because I'm not sure how to word the thing that I'm looking for on my Ubuntu machine. When on windows I can very easily and intuitively see that now I have installed the driver for the WiFi adapter, that I can access the internet through that adapter and a light comes on on the device. On Ubuntu however after installing the driver I don't see how I can access the internet 'through' that adapter? It is a laptop which already had WiFi before and it is still connected now, but the light hasn't come on on the device and the signal strength is not stronger.

Answer (score 2):

The zebulon2/rtl8814au repository from the other answer does not seem to be in active development as the most recent update was some years ago, and therefore it may not work on newer kernels.

I was able to get T9UH AC1900 working Ubuntu 20.04 using the [morrownr/8814au](https://github.com/morrownr/8814au) repository.

Instructions summary (please see above link for details):

1. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and then reboot
2. `sudo apt install -y dkms git build-essential`
3. `mkdir -p ~/src` to create a folder to download the source
4. `cd ~/src`
5. `git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8814au.git` to download the driver source
6. `cd ~/src/8814au`
7. `sudo ./install-driver.sh` to install the driver. During the installation script, select `N` to edit driver options and `Y` to reboot

After rebooting, the adapter will appear as *TP-Link Archer T9UH* under Wi-Fi in (Gnome) Settings.

Comment: Created an account just to say thank you. This worked for me using Ubuntu 20.04 with TP-Link Archer T9-UH.