# Installing driver requires me to "make clean" but no rule to make target 'clean'

Tags: command-line, networking, drivers, wireless, software-installation

[image]

Step 2.2 says to run the commands `make` followed by `make clean` but nothing happens

```
make:
No targets found and no makefile found

make clean:
No rule to make target 'clean'
```

Output of

`ls /lib/modules/4.15.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless`

`admtek
atmel
cisco
intersil
marvell
quantenna
ray_cs.ko
rndis_wlan.ko
st
wl3501_cs.ko
ath
broadcom
intel
mac80211_hwsim.ko
mediatek
ralink
realtek
rsi
ti
zydas`

The company making the WiFi booster I'm trying to use is called tp-link and it came with a disk whose contents are primarily for installing the driver on windows and apple machines

Comment: In your document, they said "Use the terminal to __go to the driver directory__", so you just have to use `cd` to go on that folder

Comment: Thank-you damadam, I believe that I have done that, I am in /lib/modules/4.15.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless, is this not the correct directory? Additionally I have tried the same commands whilst accessing the folder on the driver disk and recieved the same errors

Comment: please provide the result of `ls /lib/modules/4.15.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless` with an edit, it could add some good informations for others members to help you

Comment: You need to download (and probably unpack) the driver's source code first. Then go to the directory containing the source code and run the `make` commands. This will compile the `.ko` file that you then copy to the `/lib/modules/...` folder. You can find detailed instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473718/285436).

Comment: Was my previous answer unsatisfactory? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179671/installing-driver-for-tp-link-archer-t9uh-ac1900-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing driver for TP-LINK Archer T9UH AC1900 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179671/installing-driver-for-tp-link-archer-t9uh-ac1900-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @chili555 your last solution didn't work, you told me to "Please edit your question to show: lsusb and also: dmesg | grep 88x2bu" and I did, and then you never came back with the next step

Comment: Sorry. Please see my edit to that question in a few minutes.